# How to combine two jQuery functions into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, jquery-on

I've following two functions in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change','.states',function(){ 
  //on change of select 
});

$(document).on('click','.date_control',function(){ 
 //on click of input .date_control 
});
```

How to combine the above two functions into one function so that I can use it with my AJAX function which is as below:

```
$(function() {
  $(".add_new_rebate").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var manufacturer_id =  $("#company_id").val();

    /*if($.active > 0) { //or $.active      
      request_inprogress();
    } else {*/  
      var next_rebate_no = $('.rebate_block').length + 1;
      var rebate_no      = $('.rebate_block').length + 1;

    if ($('.rebate_block').length>0) { 
      rebate_no = rebate_no+1;
    }

      $('.add_new_rebate').attr('disabled','disabled');
    //}

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_rebate_by_product.php",
      data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'create_rebate', 'next_rebate_no':next_rebate_no, 'rebate_no':rebate_no, 'manufacturer_id':manufacturer_id},  
      beforeSend: function() { 
        $('.table-responsive').after("<img src='http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/img/ajax-loader.gif' class='load' alt='Loading...'>");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if(jQuery.trim(data)=="session_time_out") {
        window.location.href = site_url+'admin/login.php?timeout=1';                
        } else {
          $('.rebate_block').append(data);
          $('.add_new_rebate').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        $('.load').remove();
      }
    });    
 });   
});
```

If you have any other way than combining the above two function into one then also it will be fine. My requirement is to incorporate the code of these two functions into the above AJAX function as I'm generating the two HTML controls dynamically and I want to apply the jQuery classes to them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not make the action (everything inside `click`) a function and call it from both event handlers?

Comment: @xFortyFourx:I'm not getting your idea clearly, but it sounds it may work. Would you please post your answer so that I can get what you are saying?

Comment: How about this? Use a common function then call it when `click` and `change` whatever. example like we use `class`. `$(document).on('change','.states',function(){ 
  //on change of select
  commonFunction(); 
});

$(document).on('click','.date_control',function(){ 
 //on click of input .date_control 
  commonFunction();
});`

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
function do_action(){ 
 var manufacturer_id =  $("#company_id").val();

    /*if($.active > 0) { //or $.active      
      request_inprogress();
    } else {*/  
      var next_rebate_no = $('.rebate_block').length + 1;
      var rebate_no      = $('.rebate_block').length + 1;

    if ($('.rebate_block').length>0) { 
      rebate_no = rebate_no+1;
    }

      $('.add_new_rebate').attr('disabled','disabled');
    //}

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_rebate_by_product.php",
      data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'create_rebate', 'next_rebate_no':next_rebate_no, 'rebate_no':rebate_no, 'manufacturer_id':manufacturer_id},  
      beforeSend: function() { 
        $('.table-responsive').after("<img src='http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/img/ajax-loader.gif' class='load' alt='Loading...'>");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if(jQuery.trim(data)=="session_time_out") {
        window.location.href = site_url+'admin/login.php?timeout=1';                
        } else {
          $('.rebate_block').append(data);
          $('.add_new_rebate').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        $('.load').remove();
      }
    }); 
}

$(document).on('change','.states',function(){ 
  //on change of select 
  do_action();
  return false;
});

$(document).on('click','.date_control',function(){ 
 //on click of input .date_control 
 do_action();
 return false;
});
```

I'm assuming the reason why you asked the question is to avoid using the same code inside both events, this way, it's much cleaner. No repeating.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure if I understood the point correctly, but I you can define a `function withName () {}`, so you can reference that function from withing the event handlers.

Here `doStuff` is called either on »change« or on »click«

```
function doStuff (e) {
    //the stuff to do
}

$(document).on('change','.states', doStuff);

$(document).on('click','.date_control',doStuff);
```

I hope that is what you are asking for…

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link:

[How to combine two jQuery functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362839/how-to-combine-two-jquery-functions?rq=1)

And the answer can answer your question:

you simply use the same selector for both your action and your confirm

Answer (score 0):

```
function handler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var manufacturer_id =  $("#company_id").val();

    /*if($.active > 0) { //or $.active      
      request_inprogress();
    } else {*/  
      var next_rebate_no = $('.rebate_block').length + 1;
      var rebate_no      = $('.rebate_block').length + 1;

    if ($('.rebate_block').length>0) { 
      rebate_no = rebate_no+1;
    }

      $('.add_new_rebate').attr('disabled','disabled');
    //}

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "add_rebate_by_product.php",
      data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'create_rebate', 'next_rebate_no':next_rebate_no, 'rebate_no':rebate_no, 'manufacturer_id':manufacturer_id},  
      beforeSend: function() { 
        $('.table-responsive').after("<img src='http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/img/ajax-loader.gif' class='load' alt='Loading...'>");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if(jQuery.trim(data)=="session_time_out") {
        window.location.href = site_url+'admin/login.php?timeout=1';                
        } else {
          $('.rebate_block').append(data);
          $('.add_new_rebate').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        $('.load').remove();
      }
    });    
 }


$(document).on('change','.states', handler);
$(document).on('click','.date_control', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, then the following should work:

```
$( '.states, .date_control' ).on( 'click change',  function ( event ) {
    if( ( event.type == 'change' && event.target.className == 'states' )
        || ( event.type == 'click' && event.target.className == 'date_control' ) ) {
        //process event here
    };
} );
```